# Comparing an empty jagged array to 3x3 jagged array to match a sequence of numbers columns not matching but rows do

Tags: c#

I am making a Tic-Tac-Toe game. I am using two jagged arrays to determine the winner. One array is just empty and is assigned the grid number in a switch statement. The other holds all the possible combinations (probably not the best way to do this.)

```
int[][] sequence = //Player fills this up with grid selection, like 1,2 3
        {
            new int[] {0,0,0}, //players selects [0][0] put a 1 here etc.
            new int[] {0,0,0},
            new int[] {0,0,0},

        };
```

Here is the other jagged array with all possible winning combinations.

```
int[][] getsequence = 
     {
            new int[] {1,2,3},
            new int[] {4,5,6},
            new int[] {7,8,9},
            new int[] {1,4,7},
            new int[] {2,5,8},
            new int[] {3,6,9},
            new int[] {1,5,9},
            new int[] {9,5,1},
            new int[] {3,2,1},
            new int[] {6,5,4},
            new int[] {9,8,7},
            new int[] {7,4,1},
            new int[] {8,5,2},
            new int[] {9,6,3},
            new int[] {3,5,7},
            new int[] {7,5,3}
```

Here is the algorithm to see if there is a match.

```
public static void checkWinner(Player p)
    {

        foreach (int[] row in p.Sequence)
        {
            foreach (int[] row2 in p.GetSequence)
            {
                if (Enumerable.SequenceEqual(row, row2))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Win");
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Here is the switch statement kinda controlling this stuff.

```
public static string[,] updateGameBoard(string[,] matrix, int selection, Player p)
    {
        switch (selection)
        {
            case 1:
                matrix[0, 0] = p.Type;
                p.Sequence[0][0] = 1;
                break;
            case 2:
                matrix[0, 1] = p.Type;
                p.Sequence[0][1] = 2;
                break;
            case 3:
                matrix[0, 2] = p.Type;
                p.Sequence[0][2] = 3;
                break;
            case 4:
                matrix[1, 0] = p.Type;
                p.Sequence[1][0] = 4;
                break;
            case 5:
                matrix[1, 1] = p.Type;
                p.Sequence[1][1] = 5;
                break;
            case 6:
                matrix[1, 2] = p.Type;
                p.Sequence[1][2] = 6;
                break;
            case 7:
                matrix[2, 0] = p.Type;
                p.Sequence[2][0] = 7;
                break;
            case 8:
                matrix[2, 1] = p.Type;
                p.Sequence[2][1] = 8;
                break;
            case 9:
                matrix[2, 2] = p.Type;
                p.Sequence[2][2] = 9;
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
                break;

        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        return matrix;
    }
```

The matrix 2D array is just a way for me to convert the numbers to "O" or "X"
That is what `p.Type` is doing. `p` is the player object.

```
string[,] matrix =
        {
            {"1","2","3" },
            {"4","5","6" },
            {"7","8","9" }
        };
```

Anyway, it seems like it is almost working. The rows like, 123, 456 etc seem to work and the player wins the game. But if I put all "O's" in 147 for example, nothing happens. I debugged it and the row in the foreach loop seems to be the problem. I will say when I debug, the `p.GetSequence` (row2) shows each array as 123, 456, 789, etc. The `p.Sequence` (row) in the foreach loop shows 100, then on the next top iteration 400, then 700. So it makes sense I think that the rows work, but not the columns. Because they don't match. That is my theory anyway. How do I compare the columns as rows?

Lastly I don't know if this matters but I has a version of this that did work (sorta). `Sequence` and `getSequence` was just global, not in the player objects. Problem was it would say player won eventually that was not in sequence. Plus each player needs its own jagged arrays, otherwise how would you separate the X from O.

Yep, I thinks that it, I need to transpose the column into a row. Like I said when I debug getSequence it displays the values as rows, sequence is displaying the values as columns. When I put values as column, but if I enter 123 it is the row. I see articles on how to do this. But if anyone has a simple way please to do this please let me know.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: If you want to be clever about it, use a 3x3 [magic square](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/68271.html). When arranged correctly, the winning player's cells will always add to 15, so you wouldn't need this sort of sequence matching.

Comment: *criticize my code please* Consider abandoning that odd java mixed case naming (`checkWinner{}`, `updateGameBoard`) and using *verbs* as class or var names (`getsequence` - it is a sequence, not a get...).  Take a cue from the naming style in use in the myriad of classes and methods in the NET framework

Comment: If you have a solution, you can post it as an answer. Self-answers are perfectly acceptable and encouraged. Please don't edit answers into the question.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, probably not the best algorithm but it works. The inner loop still rolls 16 times even if it finds a match, so I just used a bool.

```
if (player1.Turn > 2)
        {
            foreach (int[] row in player1.Sequence)
            {
                foreach (int[] row2 in player1.GetSequence)
                {
                    foreach (int[] col in player1.TrackCol)
                    {
                        if (Enumerable.SequenceEqual(row, row2))
                        {
                            winner = true;
                        }
                        else if(Enumerable.SequenceEqual(col, row2))
                        {
                            winner = true; 

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is the switch statement:

```
public static string[,] updateGameBoard(string[,] matrix, int selection, Player p)
    {
        switch (selection)
        {
            case 1:
                matrix[0, 0] = p.Type;
                p.Sequence[0][0] = 1;
                p.TrackCol[0][0] = 1;
                break;
            case 2:
                matrix[0, 1] = p.Type;
                p.Sequence[0][1] = 2;
                p.TrackCol[0][0] = 2;
                break;
            case 3:
                matrix[0, 2] = p.Type;
                p.Sequence[0][2] = 3;
                p.TrackCol[0][0] = 3; 
                break;
            case 4:
                matrix[1, 0] = p.Type;
                p.Sequence[1][0] = 4;
                p.TrackCol[0][1] = 4;
                break;
            case 5:
                matrix[1, 1] = p.Type;
                p.Sequence[1][1] = 5;
                p.TrackCol[0][1] = 5; 
                break;
            case 6:
                matrix[1, 2] = p.Type;
                p.Sequence[1][2] = 6;
                p.TrackCol[0][1] = 6; 
                break;
            case 7:
                matrix[2, 0] = p.Type;
                p.Sequence[2][0] = 7;
                p.TrackCol[0][2] = 7;
                break;
            case 8:
                matrix[2, 1] = p.Type;
                p.Sequence[2][1] = 8;
                p.TrackCol[0][2] = 8; 
                break;
            case 9:
                matrix[2, 2] = p.Type;
                p.Sequence[2][2] = 9;
                p.TrackCol[0][2] = 9; 
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
                break;
```